# Python .replace() function wont work with accented characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

Im using python's .replace() function to find and replace to words "à Lyon"but it doesnt seem to work with accented characters. I don want to replace "a Lyon" (wothout accent) only the occurences that have the "à" accented.

ex.

```
old_str = "nous allons à Lyon et malheureusement il a Lyon"
new_str = old_str.replace("à Lyon", "found it")
```

This should return: "nous allons found it et malheureusement il a Lyon"

Any sugestions would be very much appreciated thanks.

Comment: It works correctly for me. What version/environment of Python are you using?

Comment: There are multiple ways to encode accented characters. Unicode strings should be normalized before comparing them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try making the string you want to replace a unicode string by adding a **u** in front of the quotes.

it works for me either way, I am on python 3.10.6

```
old_str = "nous allons à Lyon et malheureusement il a Lyon"
new_str = old_str.replace(u"à Lyon", "found it") #now a unicode string
print(new_str)
```

Comment: Unicode strings have been the default since Python 3.0. The `u` prefix is ignored and is only useful for backwards compatibility with Python 2.x.

Comment: Oh, that is something I didn't know until now. Thanks.